# Ao invocar controller no codeigniter, parece sempre estar passando pelo "Welcome"

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Estou fazendo uma simples aplicação em PHP com o codeigniter, onde estou tentando acessar um controller, e aparentemente sempre que chamo esse controller, ele passa pelo welcome, exemplo:

```
localhost/estudando/Login/login
```

gera o mesmo resultado que:

```
localhost/estudando/Welcome/Login/login.
```

E da erro, volta a mesma página do Welcome só que sem css.

Comment: Tem algum .htaccess na raiz do projeto?

Comment: Qual a configuração do seu **VirtualHost**? Conforme nosso amigo falou, você tem algum **.htaccess** configurado na raiz?

Comment: Sim, tem um .htaccess, estou usando o rewrite:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME/} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser a configuração de Controller Default.

Veja se no arquivo **application/config/routes.php** contém algo assim:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
```